# How to slide a div over an image with CSS?

Tags: html, css, transition, slide

On a webpage I am working on, I have a div which contains an image and another div. The inner div is initially set to

```
opacity: 0;
```

so that it's not visible. The inner div should appear over my image when hovered. I have achieved this, but now I want to improve upon it further by having the 'overlay' div (which appears with an opacity of 0.5) slide down gradually over the image. I could do it theoretically with JavaScript but on this occasion it must be a pure CSS solution. So far my solution just makes the overlay div appear gradually (it fades in) but does not slide down as I have never done this in CSS alone.

See the image below to understand further:

[image]

The HTML:

```
<div class="img"> <img class="squareImg" src="img1.jpg"/><div class="overlay"> tweet This <br> Buy This</div></div>
    <div class="img"> <img class="squareImg" src="img3.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="img"> </img></div>
```

CSS

```
    .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
} .overlay:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}


.img{
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 2px solid yellow;
background-color: black;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -110px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it's what you were after. Check my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Here it is with a slide down thanks to a height transition.

Improvements:

- Instead of `opacity`, use `background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5)` so that the contents of the overlay remain fully opaque.
- The transition property has been simplified to `transition: all .5s`
- The outside border is created with box-shadow and the black border is now created with the border property instead of padding.
- `.overlay` has a height of 0 and on hover it is given a height of 100%. It is stretched accross the image with the combination of `left: 0` and `right: 0`
- There is no set image size, the size of the `<img>` now controls the size of the border and overlay, allowing different image sizes.

### Complete Example

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.img:hover .overlay,
.overlay:hover {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.img > img {
  display: block;/* Prevent inline gap under image*/
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
  <div class="overlay">tweet This <br>Buy This</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
  <div class="overlay">tweet This <br>Buy This</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use simple transitions for this, rather than a keyframe animation

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/realseanp/c4e08hy7/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="info">
       <span>All your info</span>
       <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #000;
    z-index:3;
}

.info {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;

}

.overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 1s all;
}

.holder:hover .info{
    top:0;
}

.holder:hover .overlay{
    opacity: .85
}
```

Comment: This has the perfect desired effect but I cannot tailor it into my code. Apologies but I have now experience with moving graphics with purely CSS alone

Comment: @omusanon i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I've updated this fiddle the have an image http://jsfiddle.net/realseanp/c4e08hy7/9/ you don't put the image in the info div. you put it in the holder div

Comment: My website: www.pagesbyz.com/n4n/index.php, the overlay is showing up incorrectly in the small screen (iphone 5s). Any tips on how to resolve it?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Looks like you have set the height of class .caption to 96%, but then later on in your stylesheet you are setting the max-height of caption to 30px and the height to 70%. That's why you are seeing the issue on iphone

Comment: Should I remove it completely, the max-height and height? Since I am setting it to top:0;

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge yeah you could remove both the max-height and the 70% unless there is a specific reason you are setting the overlay to 70%

Comment: I was using an older code but since I am setting it to top: 0 I won't need it anymore I think. I will test it out and update you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple approach using the image as background:

```css
.img{
  position:    relative;
  background:  none 50% / cover;
  width:       200px;
  height:      200px;
  margin:      0 auto;
  border:      10px solid #000;
  box-shadow:  0 0 0 2px yellow;
}

.overlay{
  position:   absolute;
  width:      100%;
  height:     0%;
  overflow:   hidden;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); /* Don't use opacity but rgba on bg */
}

.img:hover .overlay{ 
  height:     100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img" style="background-image:url(//placehold.it/300x300/aba)">
  <div class="overlay">Tweet This <br> Buy This</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to slide it down, you should use @keyframes:

```
.overlay:hover{
-webkit-animation: slide 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
animation: slide 5s;
}
@keyframes slide {
    from {height: 0px;}
    to {height: 200px;}
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from {height: 0px;}
    to {height: 200px;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This solution doesn't quite work as the overlay becomes visible and slides down until the top of the overlay div is at the bottom of the image container. Whereas I am hoping to implement something like: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-slide.php

Comment: @omusanon then use height as the element of change, from 0 to whatever you want. you can toggle it, or do a more complex animation. I edited my code.

Comment: @realseanp I think that's exactly what he wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the .overlay with a negative top position and then you can target the sibling element with the + selector and change the top position to positive.
Also you can change the transition timing by setting the `transition-duration: 2s;` to 2 sec.

```
     .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    top: -200px;
    left: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:-1;
} 
.squareImg:hover + .overlay, .overlay:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    top:10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}


.img{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #000;
    z-index:3;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    background-color: black;    
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -110px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/c4e08hy7/8/

Comment: The only problem is that it slides from above. It should behave in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/realseanp/c4e08hy7/4/

Comment: However I am having trouble implementing it still.

Comment: @AlexIncarnati - Set the hover for `.overlay:hover` as well - like `.squareImg:hover + .overlay, .overlay:hover` so that it doesn't stop working when the overlay is hovered.